# Fail2Ban: I'm having trouble creating a regex for my Dovecot filter

Tags: dovecot, regex, fail2ban

I am trying to create a regex filter for my failed Dovecot entries in the maillog file. What I have created is:

```
.*dovecot: auth: sql\(.*,<HOST>\): Password mismatch
```

The target line in the maillog is:

```
Dec  9 15:09:51 hawk888 dovecot: auth: sql(deals@sleepyvalley.net,166.175.59.157): Password mismatch
```

Also, when I place the variable,  in a failregex, is this case sensitive or does case matter?

Can anyone help?

Comment: These links should help you https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/master/config/filter.d/dovecot.conf http://wiki2.dovecot.org/HowTo/Fail2Ban

Comment: Thanks for the links but I've been there and done that. I have Googled for several days about creating a regex string for Fail2Ban and looking for a filter line that matches this particular sql fail line. everything I've tried so far hasn't worked. I am using SQL authentication on my server.

Answer (score 2):

I now have my failregex filter working. I tried using the '^'at the start and placed '$' at the end and my filter started working. Although the on-line Regex Test web page shows that my filter matches the target without these, I guess that when the filter is actually applied to a test, the start and end of the target string has to be set with them.